# splitting comma separated list

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Split a list into nested lists on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value)

I have a list like this:

```
['jj01','gg01',',','yy01','hh01',',','yy04','uu01']
```

How would I split this list to its elements -- splitting on `','` like this:

```
[['jj01','gg01'],['yy01','hh01'],['yy04','uu01']]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My eyes bleed!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible 'pythonic' way to do this:

```
l = ['jj01','gg01',',','yy01','hh01',',','yy04','uu01']
joined = ':'.join(l)
separated = joined.split(':,:')
final = [x.split(':') for x in separated]
```

which can be combined into the one-liner:

```
final = [x.split(':') for x in ':'.join(l).split(':,:')]
```

As pointed out in the comments, this solution will work only if the contents of the list are strings.

Comment: This works Ok, but only if the objects are strings.  It's definitely not a general solution.

Comment: @mgilson Very true, thank you for making that clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly more clever solution than I've come up with before:

```
import itertools
def iter_partition(itr,sep):
    iitr = iter(itr)
    res = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x!=sep,iitr))
    while res:
        yield res
        res = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x!=sep, iitr))

L = ['jj01','gg01',',','yy01','hh01',',','yy04','uu01']
print list(iter_partition(L,','))
```

But this fails if you can have consecutive separators:  `['foo',',',',','bar']` -- You'll never see `bar`.

---

And another itertools solution (this one is a bit more robust than the last):

```
import itertools
def iter_partition(itr,sep):
    for k,v in itertools.groupby(itr,key=lambda x:x==sep):
        if not k:
            yield (list(v))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['jj01','gg01',',','yy01','hh01',',','yy04','uu01']
b = []
d = []

for c in a:
   if c == ',':
     b.append(d)
     d = []
   else:
     d.append(c)

b.append(d)
#no b contains your split data
```

This isn't a 'clever' solution, but I think its readable at best.

Comment: I don't think the `pass` is really needed, is it?

Comment: ah yes, remnant of evolution in code. (removes it)

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated people?

```
def process(lst):
    lines = []
    temp = []
    for item in lst:
        if item != ',':
            temp.append(item)
        else:
            lines.append(temp)
            temp = []
    return lines
```

Comment: The hypocrisy in my answer is overwhelming

Answer (score 0):

The following is a more functionality oriented, albeit un-readable one-liner solution. I would recommend taking one of the more readable approaches posted here.

```
# where 'ls' is your list
foo = zip(*[iter(filter(lambda x: x != ',', ls))]*2)
```

Edit** As @mgilson correctly points out, my solution assumes you will always have two consecutive items followed by a comma. If your list were to end with an odd item out it would will be discarded.

Comment: If I read this properly, this solution assumes that you always have two consecutive items followed by a separator (`','`) as in the example.  I think that's just an example and I think that OP wants to handle the case `['foo',',','bar','baz','qux',',','foobar','barbaz']` as well.

Answer (score -1):

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List str = new List() { "jj01", "gg01", ",", "yy01", "hh01", ",", "yy04", "uu01" };
            List newval = new List();
            StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < str.Count; i++)
            {
                if (str[i] == ",")
                {
                    res.Remove(res.Length - 3, 3);
                    newval.Add(res.ToString());
                    res = new StringBuilder();
                }
                else
                    res.Append((str[i] + " , "));
                //Last item
                if (i == str.Count - 1)
                {
                    res.Remove(res.Length - 3, 3);
                    newval.Add(res.ToString());
                }

```
        }
        foreach (var item in newval)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: The asker is looking for a solution in Python, not Java.