# Split a list into sublists on a value and keep the value

Tags: python, list, split, list-comprehension

I am trying to split a list on a value and keep the value it is split on in the sub list that is created. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value) and attempted to alter it and I am coming up short.

```
import itertools


def isplit(iterable,splitters):
    return [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(iterable,lambda x:x in splitters) if not k]

foo = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (0, 1),
 (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1), (2, 3),
 (1, 2), (2, 3), (0, 1), (2, 3), (0, 1),
 (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2), (0, 1)]

for k,g in itertools.groupby(foo,lambda x:x[0] in (0,)):
    if not k:
        print k,list(g)
```

The above code returns

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(2, 3)]
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

I want it to return:

```
[(0,1),(1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(0,1),(2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(0,1),(2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(0,1),(2, 3)]
[(0,1),(1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Where do you use your `isplit` function? Also, please wrap the lines so that you don't have to scroll to the right.

Comment: Actually, I don't. That is from the solution I found elsewhere and the loop at the bottom is me rewriting that solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the split group:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> foo = [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (0, 1), (2, 3), (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2), (0, 1)]
>>> splitpoint = []
>>> for k,g in itertools.groupby(foo,lambda x:x[0] in (0,)):
...     if k:
...         splitpoint = list(g)
...     else:
...         print splitpoint + list(g)
... 
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

or create your own generator:

```
def group_splitter(it, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x
    group = []
    for item in iter(it):
        if key(item) and group:
            yield group
            group = []
        group.append(item)
    if group:
        yield group
```

This yields that last `(0, 1)` tuple as well:

```
>>> def group_splitter(it, key=None):
...     if key is None:
...         key = lambda x: x
...     group = []
...     for item in iter(it):
...         if key(item) and group:
...             yield group
...             group = []
...         group.append(item)
...     if group:
...         yield group
... 
>>> for g in group_splitter(foo, lambda x: x[0] == 0):
...     print g
... 
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2), (1, 2)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
[(0, 1), (2, 3)]
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
[(0, 1)]
```