# Python: Parse a list of strings into a dictionnary

Tags: python, parsing

This is somewhat complicated. I have a list that looks like this:

```
['19841018 ID1\n', ' Plunging oil... \n', 'cut in the price \n', '\n', '19841018 ID2\n', ' The U.S. dollar...  \n', 'the foreign-exchange markets \n', 'late New York trading \n', '\n']
```

In my list, the `'\n'` is what separate a story. What I would like to do is to create a dictionary from the above list that would like this:

```
dict = {ID1: [19841018, 'Plunging oil... cut in the price'], ID2: [19841018, 'The U.S. dollar... the foreign-exchange markets']}
```

You can see that my `KEY` of my dictionnary is the `ID` and the items are the `year` and the combination of the stories. Is that doable?

- My IDs, are in this format `J00100394`, `J00384932`. So they all start with `J00`.

Comment: yes, but what have you tried? show us some code?

Comment: @avi you have a good point. I am working with `itertools - izip` and so far I have a mess. I will post my tentative code soon. What I am struggling with is how to combine the stories.

Comment: What are the constraints of ID token

Comment: @MicheleD'Amico The format of all ID token look like this: `J0030484920`. So they all start with `J00`. What I am trying now is to loop over each entry in my list, find the entry when there is a `J00` and store it as a key an so on.

Comment: @plug4 as soon as I in office I'll code a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part is split your list by any value, so i've take this part from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value).
Then i've parsed the list parts to built the `res` dict

```
>>> import itertools
>>> def isplit(iterable,splitters):
...     return [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(iterable,lambda x:x in splitters) if not k]
... 
>>> l = ['19841018 ID1\n', ' Plunging oil... \n', 'cut in the price \n', '\n', '19841018 ID2\n', ' The U.S. dollar...  \n', 'the foreign-exchange markets \n', 'late New York trading \n', '\n']
>>> res = {}
>>> for sublist in isplit(l,('\n',)):
...     id_parts = sublist[0].split()
...     story    = ' '.join (sentence.strip() for sentence in sublist[1:])
...     res[id_parts[1].strip()] = [id_parts[0].strip(), story]
... 
>>> res
{'ID2': ['19841018', 'The U.S. dollar... the foreign-exchange markets late New York trading'], 'ID1': ['19841018', 'Plunging oil... cut in the price']}
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the help. I need to study this code more carefully. I am quite new to `itertools`. I would have complicated my life so much more without this code...

Comment: In fact `.split()` is new to me as well. That really simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

I code an answer that use generator. The idea is that every time that start an id token the generator return the last key computed. You can costumize by change the `check_fun()` and how to mix the part of the description.

```
def trailing_carriage(s):
    if s.endswith('\n'):
        return s[:-1]
    return s

def check_fun(s):
    """
    :param s:Take a string s
    :return: None if s dosn't match the ID rules. Otherwise return the
    name,value of the token
    """
    if ' ' in s:
        id_candidate,name = s.split(" ",1)
        try:
            return trailing_carriage(name),int(id_candidate)
        except ValueError:
            pass


def parser_list(list, check_id_prefix=check_fun):
    name = None #key dict
    id_candidate = None
    desc = "" #description string
    for token in list:
        check = check_id_prefix(token)
        if check is not None:
            if name is not None:
                """Return the previous coputed entry"""
                yield name,id_val,desc
            name,id_val = check
        else:
            """Append the description"""
            desc += trailing_carriage(token)
    if name is not None:
        """Flush the last entry"""
        yield  name,id_val,desc


>>> list = ['19841018 ID1\n', ' Plunging oil... \n', 'cut in the price \n', '\n', '19841018 ID2\n', ' The U.S. dollar...  \n', 'the foreign-exchange markets \n', 'late New York trading \n', '\n']
>>> print {k:[i,d] for k,i,d in parser_list(list)}
{'ID2': [19841018, ' Plunging oil... cut in the price  The U.S. dollar...  the foreign-exchange markets late New York trading '], 'ID1': [19841018, ' Plunging oil... cut in the price ']}
```