# Split nested list on value

Tags: python, split, nested-lists

How can I split a nested list like the one below and get back the top list with groups of the "sublists" based on certain "breakpoints"?
I did it with a for loop below, but I'm not sure it's good enough for lists with hundreds or thousands of sublists.
I also tried fiddling with the [answer to question 4322705](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4322780/2253944) but I don't really understand the answer in the first place.
The context here is csv data with possible multiple headers and data sets stacked inside the file.

```
a = [['AAAA', 'b', 'c'], 
     ['b', 'c', 'd'],
     ['c', 'd', 'e'],
     ['d', 'e', 'f'],
     ['AAAA', '1', '2'],
     ['b', '2', '3'],
     ['c', '3', '4'],
     ['d', '4', '5']]
b = []
for i in a:
    if i[0] == 'AAAA':
        b.insert(0, [])
    b[0].append(i)

print "b = ", b

# Output:
# b = [[['AAAA', 'b', 'c'], 
#       ['b', '2', '3'], 
#       ['c', '3', '4'], 
#       ['d', '4', '5']], 
#      [['AAAA', '1', '2'], 
#       ['b', 'c', 'd'], 
#       ['c', 'd', 'e'], 
#       ['d', 'e', 'f']]]
```

Comment: cna you explain what you mean by *based on certain "breakpoints* ? whats the logic ?

Comment: Thanks. I updated the sample code to better reflect the "breakpoints", which are just a nested list like the others but with a key/header value in it (in this case it's AAAA).

Comment: @pjgb Your code is correct, easy to understand and not obviously slow. May I suggest that you use it as is and think about optimizing it if and only if the need arises, as from profiling your application?

Comment: @gboffi Certainly, it works very well for what I'm doing and millisecond speed is not neccessarily a priority. I was just wondering if there was some part of the python libraries that was better to use in this case. The python docs can be tough to understand for a newbie whose native language is not English. :)