# Dictionary Assigning multiple lists from input file from character

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to parse and then edit the text that lives between `{` and a `}`. The information is different(in between the curly braces) so I would need to be able to have these results separated in some type of buffer to test the /test and /example for each one.

**Information in file**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite /test redirectexample.com/test permanent;
    rewrite /  http://redirectedexample.com permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.com;
    rewrite /example testing.com/example permanent;
    rewrite /  http://www.testing.com permanent;
}
```

**Script**

```
import.os
InputFile= open('/tmp/redirect.conf', 'r')
dict = {}

file =InputFile.readlines()

parsing = False
for line in file:
    if line.startswith("}"):
        parsing = False
    if parsing:
        # Run some command here        
    if line.startswith("server {"):
        parsing = True
```

I am not sure where to start calling the dictionary as I want to somehow call everything between the first `server {` and `}`. The final goal is to be able to run a curl to test the example.com/test redirection and test.com/example redirect get the output from this and diff that to what is currently in our configuration files. The purpose of this is to audit these prior to moving them to avoid keeping configurations that are no longer needed. I had trouble finding info on this, if there is a document somewhere I need to RTFM then please feel free to drop a link.

**Edit**

Things looking for script to do:

1. Take nginx server block's and grab value(s) of "server_name"
2. Grab value of rewrite /test /example <-- actual string is random
3. Test both of these value's with `curl -w "%{url_effective}\n" -I -L
   -s -S $m -o /dev/null`
4. Then diff the curl output to whats rewritten.

Take note that I don't need to parse example.com/example as the /example redirection is in a different server block.

Hope this makes more since. There are thousands of server blocks hence the reason for this.

Comment: 'somehow call everything between' ? What's 'everything' in here?

Comment: Try regex to get the data in the server blocks: https://regex101.com/r/uW3yB6/1

Comment: I meant everything being all parts in between the curly brackets. These are nginx server calls, I need to parse each server call separately.

Comment: Thinking I would need dict1 to be the first server block and dict2 to be the second. So that I can use something to search all dict# in order to search the /test and /example bits.

Comment: Give an example of the dictionary data structure you want to represent the data.

Comment: You need to show us the expected output that corresponds to that input data. BTW, `dict` is a bad choice for a variable name as it shadows the built-in `dict` type. Also, you are using the word "call" in a confusing way: generally "call" is what you do with a function, eg `open('/tmp/redirect.conf', 'r')` is a function call.

Comment: Appreciate the information, I am new to python so my lingo isn't the best thus making this more difficult. I added my expectations of the script if that helps understand what I am looking to do.

Comment: Is your nginx config *exactly* like this for every single `server {}` block?

Comment: yes every block starts with "server {" and ends with "}"

Comment: @user3149615: What I mean to say is that nginx config files are usually more complicated than this, with `location {}` blocks inside of `server` blocks and other stuff. Was this file generated by something else, or are you just simplifying the structure?

Comment: Do you want to create something like this: `{'example.com':[{'old': '/test', 'new': 'redirectexample.com/test'}, {'old': '/', 'new': 'http://redirectedexample.com'}], 'test.com':[{'old': '/example', 'new': 'testing.com/example'}, {'old': '/', 'new': 'http://www.testing.com'}]}` ?

Comment: I only had a handful of configurations that were including location details. So those were already moved. Now all of them are just like these examples. However I do have many server blocks that have multiple server_name's in one block.

Comment: something like that looks about right. keep in mind I have some blocks that have 10-20 different /test style redirections. With multiple domains pointing to those. Meaning larger server blocks, but same syntax.

Comment: It appears you have reached the point where your question is asking for code that does 4 separate things.   Why don't you start with trying to implement the first one, and ask a question about anything you have trouble with in just that first step.   As it stands, this question is too broad - it's asking "how do I write a program to do this whole task".

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method that splits the data into nested lists and then constructs a dict. I'm largely guessing at the desired data structure. Disclaimer: there is likely a more efficient way of doing this with regex, and this method isn't ideal if reading the entire file into memory is going to be an issue.

```
import itertools


def isplit(iterable, splitters):  # thank you http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322780/6085135
    return [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(iterable,lambda x:x in splitters) if not k]


with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

# split the data into lists
data = data.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace(';', ' ;')
data = data.split()
data = isplit(data, ('server',))

# construct dict from sublists
servers = {}
for block in data:
    block = isplit(block, (';',))
    server = {}
    for item in block:
        key, value = item[0], ' '.join(item[1:])
        if key not in server.keys():
            server[key] = value
        else:
            if isinstance(server[key], list):
                server[key] = server[key].append(value)
            else:
                server[key] = [server[key], value]
    server_name = server.pop('server_name')
    servers.update({server_name: server})

print(servers)
```

Output:

```
{
  'test.com': 
    {
      'listen': ['80', '443 ssl'], 
      'rewrite': ['/example testing.com/example permanent', '/ http://www.testing.com permanent']
    }, 
  'example.com': 
    {
      'listen': ['80', '443 ssl'], 
      'rewrite': ['/test redirectexample.com/test permanent', '/ http://redirectedexample.com permanent']
    }
}
```