# Convert a 1D list to 2D at every "\n" - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to convert a 1D list to 2D whenever there is `\n` in it.

```
a = ['a', 'b', '\n', 'c', 'd']
```

to

```
a = [['a', 'b']['c', 'd']]
```

Can anyone help me?

**Edit**

This is because I have a string

```
a = """\
f:         1000:000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 f:         2000:000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
f:         0000:000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 f:         0000:000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
f:         0000:000 000 000 000 000 000 000 666 000 000 000 000 f:         0000:000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
f:         0000:000 000 000 000 000 333 000 000 000 000 000 000 f:         0000:000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000
"""
```

So when I convert it into listby doing `list(a)`, at every line break I get `\n`, so I just want to split it there.

Comment: dublicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value

Comment: @a.smiet updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way is to join the list to make string. Then split it on '\n' and convert the each string in the list to sub list:

```
>>> a_string = ''.join(a)
>>> map(list, a_string.split())
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

However if you do not want to go with this approach, below is the simple logic based on `for` loop:

```
>>> my_list = []
>>> sub_list = []
>>> for item in a:
...     if item != '\n':
...         sub_list.append(item)
...     else:
...         my_list.append(sub_list)
...         sub_list = []
...
>>> my_list.append(sub_list)
>>> my_list
[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```