# Python combining two lists into a dictionary

Tags: python

I have two lists which I want to combine into a dictionary.

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [1,2]
```

I want to repeat list b once a = zero.

```
c = { 1:0 , 1:2...1:6 , 2:0 , 2:1 , 2:2 ,...2:6}
```

Whats the pythonic way to write such a code?

Comment: dictionaries have unique keys.

Comment: Your output isn't possible, so there isn't a pythonic way

Comment: Hard to see what you are trying to do here, but take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value) using groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get an output similar to that is to slice out the a list and keep unique keys of `b` in `c`

I'm not aware of a pythonic way for that

```
from collections import deque

a = [0,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,3]
b = [1,2,3]

if not a.count(0) == len(b):
    raise RuntimeError("not enough zeros")

c = {}

idx = a.index(0)
q = deque(b)
while q:
    try:
        next_idx = a.index(0, idx+1)
        head, a = a[0:next_idx], a[next_idx:]
        val = head
    except ValueError as e:
        val = a
    c[q.popleft()] = val
    idx = next_idx
```

`{1: [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 3: [0, 3]}`

---

Or, as commented for tuples and inspired by this post

[Split a list into nested lists on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value)

```
import itertools
def isplit(iterable,splitters):
    return [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(iterable,lambda x: x in splitters) if not k]

split_on = 0
groups = zip(b, map(lambda s: [split_on] + s, isplit(a, (split_on, ))))
for g in groups:
    print(g)
```

output

```
(1, [0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
(2, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
(3, [0, 3])
```

Comment: Could he use tuples to get the result he's looking for?

Comment: How would that work? The question shows `1:0, 1:2`, and you can't have duplicate keys. What would the tuples look like?

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot what tuples are.

Comment: See edit for tuple answer

Comment: @cricket_007..Thanks. That is exactly what I was trying to do, am new to python/programming and I thought I could use dictionary to parse through my data. I will research tuples.