# Pair IP addresses in a list pulled from xlrd

Tags: python, list, keyvaluepair

I have used xlrd to pull data from a column (Data Below). I need to group together the ip addressess. So ip address that appear next together in the output belong to the same pool and single ones are in a pool of their own. For example (10.100.33.183,10.100.33.184) belong to (pool1). (Pool6 =10.100.33.89)

How do I go about achieving this all help welcome.

> ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Pool Member IP', '', '10.100.33.184 (S56723FR6VL01)', '10.100.33.183 (S56723FR6VL02)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.101.33.182 (S56723FR6VL03)', '10.100.33.181 (S56723FR6VL04)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.180 (S56723FR6VL05)', '10.100.33.179 (S56723FR6VL06)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.178 (S56723FR6VL07)', '10.100.33.177 (S56723FR6VL08)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.90 (S56723FR6VL09)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.89 (S56723FR6VL0A)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.91 (S56723FR6VW01)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

Comment: You should do this as part of extracting your data from the excel.

Comment: Making following assumptions: 1: There is no way for you to group the addresses by pool when getting the xlrd response. 3: Single addresses without a pool are preceded and superceded by empty strings. 4: Address dont repeat in the response. Are these assumptions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip_data = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Pool Member IP', '', '10.100.33.184 (S56723FR6VL01)', '10.100.33.183 (S56723FR6VL02)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.101.33.182 (S56723FR6VL03)', '10.100.33.181 (S56723FR6VL04)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.180 (S56723FR6VL05)', '10.100.33.179 (S56723FR6VL06)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.178 (S56723FR6VL07)', '10.100.33.177 (S56723FR6VL08)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.90 (S56723FR6VL09)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.89 (S56723FR6VL0A)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.91 (S56723FR6VW01)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
ip_pools = [[]]  # it starts as a list with an empty list at its last (and only) index
for ip_address in ip_data[ip_data.index('Pool Member IP')+1:]:
    if not ip_address:  # ip_address is ''
        if ip_pools[-1]:  # the last element of ip_pools is NOT an empty list: []
            ip_pools.append([])  # for the next ip pool
    else:  # ip_address is not empty
        # ip_pools[-1].append(ip_address)  # if you need the whole text
        ip_pools[-1].append(ip_address.partition(' ')[0])  # if you just want the number
if [] in ip_pools:
    ip_pools.remove([])  # to remove last empty list (if exists)
```

EDIT: Corrected the for sentence

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful and quick too. I spent two days getting nowhere fast!!!

Comment: I meant it was no longer marked as correct. But it's alright, you are entitled to choose the answer that fits your question the best.

Comment: that must of been a mistake on my part as i was trying to look at it again

Comment: any change you could with another similar question @francisco https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317317/pair-port-numbers-from-list-after-xlrd-import

Answer (score 1):

@franciscosollima's solution is good. Here's another way with regex.

```
iplist = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Pool Member IP', '', '10.100.33.184 (S56723FR6VL01)', '10.100.33.183 (S56723FR6VL02)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.101.33.182 (S56723FR6VL03)', '10.100.33.181 (S56723FR6VL04)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.180 (S56723FR6VL05)', '10.100.33.179 (S56723FR6VL06)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.178 (S56723FR6VL07)', '10.100.33.177 (S56723FR6VL08)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.90 (S56723FR6VL09)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.89 (S56723FR6VL0A)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.91 (S56723FR6VW01)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']

import re

p = re.compile('[\d]+(?:\.[\d]+){3}')

pools = [[]]

for ip in iplist:
    m = p.match(ip)
    if m:
        pools[-1].append(m.group(0))
    elif not pools[-1]:
        continue
    else:
        pools.append([])

if [] in pools:
    pools.remove([])

for i, p in enumerate(pools, 1):
    print("Group " + str(i) +": " + str(p))
```

It's as simple as adding consecutive matches to the same pool. Otherwise, initialise a new one. The regex pattern will match from the start, and you may configure it detect IPv6 addresses too.

Prints out:

```
Group 1: ['10.100.33.184', '10.100.33.183']
Group 2: ['10.101.33.182', '10.100.33.181']
Group 3: ['10.100.33.180', '10.100.33.179']
Group 4: ['10.100.33.178', '10.100.33.177']
Group 5: ['10.100.33.90']
Group 6: ['10.100.33.89']
Group 7: ['10.100.33.91']
```

Comment: Great solution, very clean i like it .thanks coldspeed

Answer (score 1):

```
ips = [ip.split()[0] for ip in data if ip[0].isdigit()]
sort = sorted(ips, key= lambda ip: int(ip.split('.')[-1]))
i, l, c = 0, len(sort), 1
pools = {}
while i < l:
    if int(sort[i].split('.')[-1]) == int(sort[i+1]).split('.')[-1])-1:
        pools[c] = (sort[i], sort[i+1])
        i += 2
    else:
        pools[c] = (sort[i],)
        i += 1
    c += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

May i play a bit with itertools for an answer?

```
test = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Pool Member IP', '', '10.100.33.184 (S56723FR6VL01)', '10.100.33.183 (S56723FR6VL02)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.101.33.182 (S56723FR6VL03)', '10.100.33.181 (S56723FR6VL04)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.180 (S56723FR6VL05)', '10.100.33.179 (S56723FR6VL06)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.178 (S56723FR6VL07)', '10.100.33.177 (S56723FR6VL08)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.90 (S56723FR6VL09)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.89 (S56723FR6VL0A)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.100.33.91 (S56723FR6VW01)', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
import itertools
def isplit(iterable,splitters):
    return [list(g) for k,g in itertools.groupby(iterable,lambda x:x in splitters) if not k]
test.remove('Pool Member IP')
pool = 0
for list in isplit(test,''):
    if len(list):
        pool+=1
    print(pool, list)
```

Prints out:

```
1 ['10.100.33.184 (S56723FR6VL01)', '10.100.33.183 (S56723FR6VL02)']
2 ['10.101.33.182 (S56723FR6VL03)', '10.100.33.181 (S56723FR6VL04)']
3 ['10.100.33.180 (S56723FR6VL05)', '10.100.33.179 (S56723FR6VL06)']
4 ['10.100.33.178 (S56723FR6VL07)', '10.100.33.177 (S56723FR6VL08)']
5 ['10.100.33.90 (S56723FR6VL09)']
6 ['10.100.33.89 (S56723FR6VL0A)']
7 ['10.100.33.91 (S56723FR6VW01)']
```

Kudos to [Split a list into nested lists on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value) and google-fu

Comment: Thanks BoboDarph i just gave that link a look

Comment: Basically all I did was find a way to split a list into sublists based on a list item (which in your case is the empty element - '') and then increase a counter and print the sub-list for each non-empty sublist. And pop all the unneeded stuff from the list (which in your case is the 'Pool member IP' string).