# While loop within for loop for list of lists

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm trying to create a big list that will contain lists of strings. I iterate over the input list of strings and create a temporary list.
Input:

```
['Mike','Angela','Bill','\n','Robert','Pam','\n',...]
```

My desired output:

```
[['Mike','Angela','Bill'],['Robert','Pam']...]
```

What i get:

```
[['Mike','Angela','Bill'],['Angela','Bill'],['Bill']...]
```

Code:

```
for i in range(0,len(temp)):
        temporary = []
        while(temp[i] != '\n' and i<len(temp)-1):
            temporary.append(temp[i])
            i+=1
        bigList.append(temporary)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value appears to be what you might want to look into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing your code, I'd recommend iterating over each element directly, appending to a nested list -

```
r = [[]]
for i in temp:
    if i.strip():
        r[-1].append(i)
    else:
        r.append([])
```

Note that if `temp` ends with a newline, `r` will have a trailing empty `[]` list. You can get rid of that though:

```
if not r[-1]:
    del r[-1]
```

Another option would be using `itertools.groupby`, which the other answerer has already mentioned. Although, your method is more performant.

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
names = ['Mike','Angela','Bill','\n','Robert','Pam']
[list(g) for k,g in groupby(names, lambda x:x=='\n') if not k]
#[['Mike', 'Angela', 'Bill'], ['Robert', 'Pam']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
a_list = ['Mike','Angela','Bill','\n','Robert','Pam','\n']

result = []

start = 0
end = 0

for indx, name in enumerate(a_list):    
    if name == '\n':
        end = indx
        sublist = a_list[start:end]
        if sublist:
            result.append(sublist)
        start = indx + 1    

>>> result
[['Mike', 'Angela', 'Bill'], ['Robert', 'Pam']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop was scanning over the temp array just fine, but the while loop on the inside was advancing that index. And then your while loop would reduce the index. This caused the repitition.

```
temp = ['mike','angela','bill','\n','robert','pam','\n','liz','anya','\n'] 
# !make sure to include this '\n' at the end of temp!
bigList = [] 

temporary = []
for i in range(0,len(temp)):
        if(temp[i] != '\n'):
            temporary.append(temp[i])
            print(temporary)
        else:
            print(temporary)
            bigList.append(temporary)
            temporary = []
```