# Splitting a list based on change in value using itertools

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list that I'm trying to group by a change in value:

```
input_list = ["I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I"]
```

What I need is an output list that separates each group that starts with "I":

```
output_list = [["I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I"], ["I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I"]]
```

I've tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from itertools import groupby

input_list = ["I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I"]

output_list = [["I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I"], ["I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I"]]

for key, val in groupby(input_list, lambda x: x == "I"):
    print(list(val))
```

… it returns *almost* what I want:

```
['I']
['Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I']
['I']
['Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I']
```

Now I could go ahead and merge this, i.e., merge every other element, but that seems like a hack. I've also come up with the "classic" way of iterating:

```
ret = []
curr_list = []
for element in input_list:
    if element != "I":
        curr_list.append(element)
    if element == "I":
        if curr_list:
            ret.append(curr_list)
        curr_list = [element]
ret.append(curr_list)
```

Is there a more Pythonic way of achieving what I need?

Comment: Is "I" always the first list item? If not, can you give an example of desired input and output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a list into nested lists on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322705/split-a-list-into-nested-lists-on-a-value)

Comment: @Chris_Rands Yes, it is. Good observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the output of `groupby` a generator expression and pair the output by zipping it with itself:

```
from itertools import groupby
groups = (list(g) for _, g in groupby(input_list, 'I'.__eq__))
print([[i for l in pair for i in l] for pair in zip(groups, groups)])
```

This outputs:

```
[['I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I'], ['I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use indices to store the first instance of `I` with the following non `I` values:

```
import itertools
input_list = ["I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "I", "Non-I", "Non-I", "Non-I"]
d = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(input_list, key=lambda x:x == 'I')]
final_result = [[*d[i], *d[i+1]] for i in range(0, len(d), 2)]
```

Output:

```
[['I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I'], ['I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I']]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to find the indices where a string begins with `"I"` and use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to slice the list using these indices:

```
from itertools import islice

ix = [ix for ix,i in enumerate(input_list) if i[0]=='I'] + [len(input_list)]
input_ = iter(input_list)
[list(islice(input_, i)) for i in ix[1:]]
```

**Output**

```
[['I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I'], ['I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Also looking for the indices of the "I":s, and then creating a separate list for each chunk by slicing the input_list.

```
location_list = [i for i, x in enumerate(input_list) if x == "I"]
[input_list[i:j] for i,j in zip(location_list, location_list[1:]+[len(input_list)])]
```

With output:

```
[['I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I'], ['I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I', 'Non-I']]
```

Tried not using any imports, in case you are unable to use itertools.